# Покрас выделенной ячейки в шахматах

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

При клике мне нужно, чтобы ячейка красилась в заданный цвет. Но в моём коде при клике красится весь Canvas. Подскажите, что я делаю не так и как можно это исправить?

```
private void field_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        field.Children.Clear();

        var cellSize = field.ActualHeight / 8;

        Placement.Initialisation();

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                
                isFilled = j % 2 == 0 ? i % 2 == 0 : i % 2 != 0;
                

                var cell = new Rectangle();    

                cell.Height = cellSize;
                cell.Width = cellSize;
                cell.Fill = isSelected
                ? Brushes.Red
                : isFilled ? Brushes.RosyBrown : Brushes.White;

                cell.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                cell.StrokeThickness = 1;

                field.Children.Add(cell);

                Canvas.SetTop(cell, (i) * cellSize);
                Canvas.SetLeft(cell, (j) * cellSize);

                var text = new TextBlock();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Placement.field[i, j]))
                {
                    text.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    text.Text = Placement.field[i, j];
                }
                
                text.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                text.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                text.FontSize = 30;
                
                field.Children.Add(text);

                cell.MouseLeftButtonUp += Clicked;
                text.MouseLeftButtonUp += Clicked;

                Canvas.SetTop(text, (i) * cellSize);
                Canvas.SetLeft(text, (j) * cellSize);

                
            }
        }
    }

    public void Clicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        
        isSelected = !isSelected;

        
        SizeChangedInfo sifo = new SizeChangedInfo(field, new Size(0, 0), true, true);
        
        SizeChangedEventArgs ea = typeof(SizeChangedEventArgs)
            .GetConstructors(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance) 
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Invoke(new object[] { (field as FrameworkElement), sifo }) as SizeChangedEventArgs;
        ea.RoutedEvent = Canvas.SizeChangedEvent;

        field.RaiseEvent(ea);
    }
}
```

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это учебное задание, препод запрещает писать код нормально. см. коммент под моим ответом на предыдущий вопрос. Но я все равно нахожу странным, что рефлексия - ок, а биндинг - не ок. Либо автор нам зубы заговаривает.

Comment: @aepot `Да, я знаю, что у вас "задание такое", но тогда идите в WinForms` ... `Вы сейчас сами себе стреляете в ногу, как в плане обучения` ... `так и в плане производства проекта`. Читайте внимательно пожалуйста...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ок ок, без паники, читаю внимательно. Мне просто интересно, что это за учебное заведение такое, где препод обучает WPFу людей, на сам при этом не в теме. Ну, чтоб я детей туда случайно не отдал учиться.

Comment: @aepot Зная наше древнее образование, я не удивлен. Увы, но большинство преподов "олды", которые сами толком не знают, как работает технология, да и сами развиваться не хотят, учат лишь только то, что узнали в 90++ годах. К тому же, в большинстве случаев они обучают по старым учебникам, ибо их давно не выпускали, либо их не закупило учебное заведение. Короче, нынешнее обучение, в большинстве случаев бредовое, закинет в голову много лишнего и только небольшую горсть нужного...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я знаю ВУЗ, где до сих пор Борланд Паскаль 6 с 8086 ассемблером актуален. Но там учат код писать нормально. А здесь другая история. Типа нужно оставаться в рамках жестких требований, типа развиваться самостоятельно не приветствуется. Вот чему я крайне удивлён.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял задача перекрасить клетку, в которую нажал юзер, тогда у меня вот так получилось.

```xml
<Window x:Class="ChessBoardHardcore.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChessBoardHardcore"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid x:Name="container">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas"></Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawBoard();
    }

    private void DrawBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                bool isLight = j % 2 == 0 ? i % 2 == 0 : i % 2 != 0;
                Rectangle cell = new Rectangle
                {
                    Fill = isLight ? Brushes.Bisque : Brushes.SandyBrown
                };
                cell.MouseLeftButtonDown += Cell_MouseClick;
                cell.MouseLeftButtonUp += Cell_MouseClick;
                cell.MouseLeave += Cell_MouseLeave;
                canvas.Children.Add(cell);
            }
        ResizeBoard();
    }

    private void Cell_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle cell = (Rectangle)sender;

        if (cell.Fill == Brushes.RosyBrown)
            cell.Fill = Brushes.Bisque;
        else if (cell.Fill == Brushes.Brown)
            cell.Fill = Brushes.SandyBrown;
    }

    private void Cell_MouseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle cell = (Rectangle)sender;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (cell.Fill == Brushes.Bisque)
                cell.Fill = Brushes.RosyBrown;
            else if (cell.Fill == Brushes.SandyBrown)
                cell.Fill = Brushes.Brown;
        }
        else
        {
            if (cell.Fill == Brushes.RosyBrown)
                cell.Fill = Brushes.Bisque;
            else if (cell.Fill == Brushes.Brown)
                cell.Fill = Brushes.SandyBrown;
        }
    }

    private void ResizeBoard()
    {
        if (canvas.Children.Count < 64)
            return;
        double size = Math.Min(container.ActualHeight, container.ActualWidth);
        canvas.Width = size;
        canvas.Height = size;
        double cellSize = size / 8;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                Rectangle cell = (Rectangle)canvas.Children[i * 8 + j];
                cell.Width = cellSize;
                cell.Height = cellSize;
                Canvas.SetTop(cell, i * cellSize);
                Canvas.SetLeft(cell, j * cellSize);
            }
    }

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ResizeBoard();
    }
}
```